# Can I clone locally a Parse.com database to avoid high rate access to DB

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a database containing coordinates GPS of stores. Since I am the admin, I am able to keep adding some.

However, I am using Parse.com so I would like the users not to access the database online each time (limit database access and deal with offline matter) but instead, cloning the database on the device and each time the user launch the app, it would compare the database stored locally and the on on Parse.Com and update if needed. What is the way to do that ?

I hope I am clear enough.

Arnaud

Comment: how big is the database? and how fast does it grow?

Comment: It is pretty small. It will grow at a 2/3 added stores a day rate. I think at the end, I will have like 200 stores or so.

Comment: You could probably use the parse on-disk cache. see http://blog.parse.com/2014/04/30/take-your-app-offline-with-parse-local-datastore/

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. However it seems to me that it is not suitable for my purpose. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

1. On the first app launch select all the records from Parse.com and store them in the local database. Store date and time of the request as well.
2. Keep in database on Parse.com date of last data modification by admin. These fields in Parse.com database are available by default. (createdAt, updatedAt)
3. Each time user launched app make a request to compare dates. Request entries which are created or modified only after specific date.

Comment: steps 1 and 3 are the same (in case 1, `specific date` is `0`). (also, you want entries created *and modified* (which is also hinted by point 2)).

Comment: Yes 1 and 3 are the same. Added both just to explain the use case. Thanks, added info about modification date in 3.